# Why is a custom object not visible when creating a new Custom Report Type?

Tags: custom-report-type

I have a lookup field from Case-->Entitlement (Custom Object)
[image]

- Entitlement is an object from a managed package

I want to build a new CRT that will hold data from both objects. The entitlement object is not available to select as a 'Primary Object'.

[image]

And is also missing when selecting 'Cases' as primary.

These are the settings of the Entitlement object

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one checkbox Allow Reports which is unchecked by default. Make sure you have checked that. Without you cannot object for report.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The 'Enable Reports' is checked. I modified my question (this is an object from a managed package)

Comment: @Saariko There are 2 object are you sure this is not one of them. Also check if someone might changed the label.

Comment: thanks. The long label that was in the pick list is the one the confused me. Thank you